# Problem with extracting BioPerl-1.6.1.tar.gz when running VEP's INSTALL.pl script

Tags: linux, perl

I'm trying to install version 77 of Variant Effect Predictor (VEP) on a linux machine and keep encountering errors when running `perl INSTALL.pl`. After resolving an error with missing the perl module `Archive::Extract`, I ran into this error:

```
Hello! This installer is configured to install v77 of the Ensembl API for use by the VEP.
It will not affect any existing installations of the Ensembl API that you may have.

It will also download and install cache files from Ensembl's FTP server.

Checking for installed versions of the Ensembl API...done

Setting up directories

Downloading required files
 - fetching ensembl
** GET https://github.com/Ensembl/ensembl/archive/release/77.zip ==> 501 Protocol scheme 'https' is not supported (LWP::Protocol::https not installed)
** GET https://github.com/Ensembl/ensembl/archive/release/77.zip ==> 501 Protocol scheme 'https' is not supported (LWP::Protocol::https not installed)
Trying to fetch using curl
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   124    0   124    0     0    730      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   729
100 10.7M    0 10.7M    0     0  3535k      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:-- 4859k
 - unpacking ./Bio/tmp/ensembl.zip
 - moving files
 - fetching ensembl-variation
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   134    0   134    0     0    737      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   740
100 3986k    0 3986k    0     0  4378k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 7182k
 - unpacking ./Bio/tmp/ensembl-variation.zip
 - moving files
 - fetching ensembl-funcgen
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   132    0   132    0     0    798      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   800
100 2016k    0 2016k    0     0  3354k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 5156k
 - unpacking ./Bio/tmp/ensembl-funcgen.zip
 - moving files
 - fetching BioPerl
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   178  100   178    0     0   2695      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2738
100  9340  100  9340    0     0  46698      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 46698
 - unpacking ./Bio/tmp/BioPerl-1.6.1.tar.gz
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Invalid header block at offset unknown at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Archive/Extract.pm line 893.
Unable to extract '/opt/vep/src/ensembl-vep/ensembl-tools-release-77/scripts/variant_effect_predictor/Bio/tmp/BioPerl-1.6.1.tar.gz': Invalid header block at offset unknown at INSTALL.pl line 905.
Error listing contents of archive '/opt/vep/src/ensembl-vep/ensembl-tools-release-77/scripts/variant_effect_predictor/Bio/tmp/BioPerl-1.6.1.tar.gz': /bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive
/bin/tar: Skipping to next header
/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
 at INSTALL.pl line 905.
Extract failed due to errors at INSTALL.pl line 905.
Can't call method "error" on an undefined value at INSTALL.pl line 905.
```

And line 905 of the INSTALL.pl script is:

```
900 # unpack a tarball
901 sub unpack_arch {
902   my ($arch_file, $dir) = @_;
903 
904   my $ar = Archive::Extract->new(archive => $arch_file);
905   my $ok = $ar->extract(to => $dir) or die $ae->error;
906   unlink($arch_file);
907 }
```

I'm not familiar enough with perl to know what's going wrong exactly, but I tried un-taring the BioPerl-1.6.1.tar.gz myself with `tar -xvzf` and that did not work. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This is a bug in BioPerl or probably this VEP install script, so you probably need to ask them for support - https://bioperl.org/Support.html - however I will note that the latest version of BioPerl on CPAN is 1.7.2. Also see https://bioperl.org/INSTALL.html

Comment: Sounds like the file is corrupted somehow if multiple programs couldn't read it.

Answer (score 0):

this archive seems corrupted : /opt/vep/src/ensembl-vep/ensembl-tools-release-77/scripts/variant_effect_predictor/Bio/tmp/BioPerl-1.6.1.tar.gz

/bin/tar is giving you an error "/bin/tar: This does not look like a tar archive"

can you replace this file or delete it and restart the installation?